# Should implementation of an interface available in ejb client project?

Tags: java, ejb

I have the following session bean:

```
public class JVTActivationSessionImpl implements SessionBean {
    public OrderValue makeOrderValue(String typeName)
            throws OssIllegalArgumentException, RemoteException {
        return new OrderValueImpl();
    }
}
```

And on the client project, I have the interface `OrderValue` available.

But when I run the client, it throws "`Class not found exception for OrderValueImpl`"

After I put the `OrderValueImpl` class available to client project, it is ok.

My question is why should the implementation class (`OrderValueImpl`) available to client since I already have the interface (`OrderValue`) available?

Shouldn't it automatically marshal/unmarsh the object on the fly?

Comment: Men! You want to drive a blueprint of a car instead of a car!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the implementation of the objects that go into the wire. You don't need the implementation of the SessionBean itself.

Otherwise, how the client would know how to unmarshall the bytes coming from the net or which object to create if he doesn't know the impl class?